# Collection of information on all youtube videos

Tags: web-services, web, youtube, analytics

I am a first year C.S student...so please  bear with me. I want to create a website which hosts all information about Youtube videos, like the number of views, likes, dislikes so that I can do some analytics on it. So how do I go about getting that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [YouTube Analytics API's](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/) to obtain reporting metrics about YouTube Channels and Videos.  Specific information on the metrics and reports available:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/dims
- https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets

To access the API's you will need to use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) and register with Google API's.  Create or use an existing Google Account and navigate to the [Google API's Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/).  Here you can manage the different API's you have access to.

You didn't mention what language you're using, but Google publishes libraries to help you build your application that take care of a lot of the low level implementation details.  You can find the client libraries for Google API's [here](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/api/libraries).  YouTube client library can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtubeAnalytics/v1).

In short, you will need to do some research.  Google has excellent documentation and I hope the links provided can get you started.  I recommend reading through the links and building a quick POC to get familiar with how the API's work before designing your system.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, i'll get back at you after going through them all, what is POC?

Comment: It stands for "Proof of Concept".  It just means to build a simple, "dirty", implementation first to understand how it works before putting in the time and effort to design the full system.